# bash: How to replace an entire line in a text file by a part of its content

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed

I have a text file, called texto.txt in Documentos folder, with some values like the ones below:

```
cat ~/Documentos/texto.txt

65f8: Testado
a4a1: Testado 2
```

So I want to change a whole line by using a customized function which gets as parameters the new value.
The new value will always keep the first 6 characters, changing only what comes after them. Although I am testing only the first four.

Then I edited my .bashrc including my function like shown below.

```
muda() 
{ 
export BUSCA="$(echo $* | cut -c 1-4)";
sed -i "/^$BUSCA/s/.*/$*/" ~/Documentos/texto.txt ;}
```

When I run the command below it works like a charm, but I feel it could be improved.

```
muda a4a1: Testado 3
```

Result:

```
cat ~/Documentos/texto.txt

65f8: Testado
a4a1: Testado 3
```

Is there a smarter way to do this? Maybe by getting rid of BUSCA variable?

Comment: Are you sure there's no `$` missing in the sed line?

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. Adjusted already, thanks

Comment: eliminate the 2 subprocess calls for the `$(echo ... | cut ...)` with ` muda() {export BUSCA="${1}"; shift; sed -i "s/^${BUSCA}.*/${BUSCA} $*/" ~/Documentos/texto.txt;}`; if you know for a fact that you can trust the format of the input a further simplifcation: `muda() { sed -i "s/^$1.*/$*/" texto.txt;}`

Comment: I need cut to use only first 4 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write:

```sh
muda() {
    local new_line="$*"
    local key=${newline:0:4}
    sed -i "s/^${key//\//\\/}.*/${new_line//\//\\/}/" ~/Documentos/texto.txt
}
```

Notes:

- using `local` variables, not exported environment variables
- does not call out to cut, bash can extract a substring
- escaping any slashes in the variable values so the sed code is not broken.

Comment: Nice, I liked this one, thanks